# Is there an online storage option that can connect with Computercraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-computercraft

I want an online storage that can connect with Computercraft in minecraft which uses lua.

Is there some sort of online database, like mysql, that I can use in lua without installing external programs?

I only have access to Computercraft computers in-game. And, I cannot install an external program such as luasql.  Is there any other way?

http://www.keplerproject.org/luasql/

Comment: i'm sorry for the bad grammar, thank you for editing it David

Comment: You could just use [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) if i am not misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

You could, if you have the HTTP api enabled, use a PHP script that would give you the response to your [Post](http://w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) requests. You could also [update](http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) your database with the post request should you program it correctly. Check [this](http://w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_where.asp) link.